# Macbook pro 1.1 wifi problems

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro 1.1 that has problems with the WiFi.

I have a strong wireless router that reaches the far side of my house, but with my MacBook Pro, I have to stay within 1 meter of the router to have internet connection. If I move out of the range, I lose connection.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There have been reports of the A/B/G (not N) wireless cards in the original MacBook and MacBook Pro from 2006 losing sensitivity. The best solution seems to be to replace the card. If it's any consolation, you could use this opportunity to [upgrade to N](http://store.fastmac.com/product_info.php?products_id=207).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced high ping (hundreds of ms) and failing network connectivity on my macbook when my router switched to channel 100 on 5GHz. By disabling "Auto select channel including DFS channels" I solved the issue.

There are 16 DFS channels: 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, and 144. ([DFS channels](https://www.aami.org/medical-device-connectivity/medical-device-connectivity-faqs-standards-802-11))

When I noticed the network is slow again I checked which channel is being used at the moment and it was channel 100 in ma case. I tried to manually select "non-DFS" channel and the ping was totally fine again!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).